# Использование внешних файлов в проекте с js и jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть довольно сложный однофайловый проект, скриптовая часть которого работает с помощью jQuery. Можно ли как-то разбить его на файлы, чтобы jQuery работала корректно?

Comment: Можно. *(8 символов нужно...)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно можно, если подключать файлы по очереди:

```html
<script src="./assets/util.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/secondutil.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/thirdutil.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/...util.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/main.js"></script>
```

Но я рекомендую Вам использовать библиотеку [RequireJS](https://requirejs.org/), которая была специально создана для подобных задач